# Are AndroidManifest.xml permissions all permissions that an App will use?

Tags: android-permissions

something that I did not clearly understood from the documentation:

Are the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` all permissions the app might ask for?

Or in other words:

- Are the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` already granted on installing?
- Can the app ask for permissions that are not in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the original versions of Android, permissions in AndroidManifest were automatically granted.  If they installed it, the app had those permissions.

In more modern versions (5.0 or 6.0), the manifest is the superset of all permissions it may ask for.  Some (like internet) are automatic.  Others require requesting at runtime.  An app may not request a permission it doesn't declare in its manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the simple overview.